$P-v$ diagrams and isotherms with two inflection points
I have a very simple naive question concerning the interpretation of the following situation. Let there be an isotherm in a $P-v$ diagram which has two inflection points (different specific volumes, same critical temperature). How am I to interpret this situation in terms of phases and phase transitions? All the examples I know are critical isotherms with a single point of inflection.
I can provide some information to perhaps make the situation more clear. My equation of state is of the form
$$
P = \frac{T}{v}-\frac{a}{v^2}+\frac{b}{v^4}+\frac{c}{d+v^4},
$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are positive, dimensionful parameters. With this equation at hand, one can show that there is a critical temperature $T_c$ such that the critical isotherm in the $P-v$ diagram exhibits two points of inflection, i.e. two pairs $(P_1,v_1)$ and $(P_2,v_2)$ where
$$
\partial P/\partial v_i=0=\partial^2P/\partial v_i^2,
$$
for fixed $T=T_c$ and certain values of $a,b,c,d$. In the standard case, where we have a single point inflection, it is straightforward to distinguish between super- and sub-critical curves. I fail to see how to deal with phase transitions in this scenario. This weird example arises in the context of black hole thermodynamics.
My understanding: there will be configurations at some temperature $T$ where two phase transitions can occur. This produces a weird phase diagram. Do we know of any physical situation with this behavior perhaps?

Can you please provide a schematic example of what you are referring to.

I added some extra information. Hope it helps.

Your equation of state is only an approximation.  For a pure material composed of a combination of saturated liquid and saturated vapor at equilibrium, the pressure and temperature are constant, and the specific volume is a weighted average of the specific volume of the saturated liquid and the saturated vapor.  Your equation oof statue only provides an approximation to this.

Sure, but still, what do I understand from the approximation in this case? I should gain some physical insight, as one does for example from the Van der Waals equation.
